# Finding computational complexity of recursive algorithm for interleaving strings

Tags: java, recursion

I have developed the following code to determine if a string s is interleaving of strings x and y. There can be repetitions of x and y within s, and characters do not have to be contiguous. For example, if string s = "11011001," string x = "110," and string y = "01," it would return true.

What I was hoping someone could help me with is determining the computational complexity of the algorithm. I have pasted the algorithm below (java) but am not sure how to find its computational complexity. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static boolean isInterleaving (String x, String y, String s) {
   if (s.length()==0)
       return true;

   if (s.charAt(0)==x.charAt(0)) {
       x = x.substring(1) + x.charAt(0);
       if (isInterleaving(x, y, s.substring(1)))
           return true;
   }
   if (s.charAt(0)==y.charAt(0)) {
       y = y.substring(1) + y.charAt(0);
       if (isInterleaving(x, y, s.substring(1)))
           return true;
   }
   return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime is `O(2^n)` where `n` is the length of the String `s`.  The way to see this is as follows:  Each time you enter the `isInterleaving` method, you perform a couple simple checks that run in `O(1)` time (assuming that the `substring()` method is `O(1)`).  If either of those checks is true, then you recurse, except that you shrink the size of the String `s` by 1.  Inside each call to `isInterleaving`, we will make either 0, 1, or 2 recursive calls to `isInterleaving`.  In the worst case, we will make 2 recursive calls to isInterleaving.  This leads to exponential runtime, since each call to `isInterleaving` can result in two additional calls.  Thus a worst-case runtime of `O(2^n)`.

Another way to deduce this is to examine the runtime as we take longer and longer String s:

Case 0 (s.length() == 0): Runtime is clearly constant, call it C.

Case 1 (s.length() == 1): Could result in two recursive calls, each of which would have runtime as described by case 0.  Hence the runtime is 2*C.

Case 2 (s.length() == 2): Could result in two recursive calls, each of which would be as in case 1, hence a runtime of 2*2*c = 2^2 * C

Inductively we see that when s.length() == n, we have a runtime of 2^n*C.  Since C is a constant, it can be ignored when considering things "Big-O", hence a runtime of `O(2^n)`.

Comment: Is this correct?  Each call to isInterleaving can lead to *two* more calls to interleaving.  That puts the complexity as o(2^n).

Comment: Also, there seem to be errors in the algorithm: There are missing checks for either x or y being empty, and I don't understand why x.charAt(0) or y.charAt(0) are being added to the end of the string, instead of just being discarded.

Comment: Ah, the characters are added at the end so to handle repetitions.  But then, must there be at least one of each of the strings x and y?  Must each use of x and y be complete?

Comment: @ThomasBitonti Ah, yes you are correct that each call can potentially lead to 2 more calls to isInterleaving, I missed that.  I will update my answer, thanks.  Also, I was only attempting to analyze the runtime of the algorithm, not necessarily the correctness or completeness (I do think there are issues with the algorithm itself).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes the charAt(0) is being added to the end of the string to allow for repetition. The conditions as to whether either x or y can be empty were not specified in the assignment, but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I know I didn't ask in the original post, but if you have any suggestions for improvement to the code itself they are more than welcome. I am a novice programmer. Thanks.

Comment: @oliveviolet24 Does "interleaving" mean it has to be one character from first string, then one from other string, then one from first, alternating like this?  Or can it be 2 from first string, 1 from second string, 3 from first, 2 from second, etc...?

Comment: The latter. So, if we have x="AB", y ="CD," and s="ACBD," it would return true. Similarly, if we have s="ABCD," it would also return true.